# C++ How to read first character from users input and ignore rest (char type)

Tags: c++

```
char Oprt;
cout << "\nPlease enter first number: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Please enter second number: ";
cin >> num2;
cout << "Now please enter operator: ";
cin >> Oprt;
while (Oprt != '+' && Oprt != '-' && Oprt != '*' && Oprt != '/')
{
    cout << "Wrong Operator please enter again: ";
    cin >> Oprt;
}
```

When user writes something like 'ffsd' as input the loop cycles for as much times as there are characters written by user but what I want is my program to read only first symbol and ignore the rest.

Comment: I don't really think the "game-engine" tag is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two valid approaches here:

- Use `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` to ignore all characters up to and including `'\n'`, or
- Use `istream::getline` to read a whole `std::string`, and then grab the initial character if the string is not empty.

In both cases you need to ignore the `'\n'` before entering the loop, because `cin >> num2` does not remove `'\n'` from the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::istream::ignore. For example, like that.

```
std::cin.ignore(MAX_INPUT_LENGTH,'\n');
```

For more info, look in the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)